# Edit iframe attributes from a widget in Adobe Captivate

Tags: javascript, widget, adobe-captivate, html5-fullscreen

I am writing a widget for Adobe Captivate, which has to work in HTML5. This widget contains a button to toggle the full screen mode. Basically, the plugin looks like that:

```js
function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
  elem = elem || document.documentElement;
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("fullscreen").addEventListener("click", toggleFullscreen);
```

```html
<button id="fullscren">Toggle full screen</button>
```

But the widget is inserted in an `iframe`, and this `iframe` does not have the `allowfullscreen` attribute, and therefore prevents the button to toggle the full screen mode.

I am looking for a way either to add the `allowfullscreen` attribute to the `iframe` by executing some Javascript from the inside of the `iframe`, either to publish the project with the correct configuration to automatically add this attribute.

I tried to use the Javascript accessor `parent.document`, but I get an error :

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Comment: The button works if I edit the CPM.js file and add the attribute `allowfullscreen: "true"` in the iframe attributes. Obviously, it is not a solution, because it requires a file edition after publishing the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `parent` attribute in Javascript is enough. You can then add the `allowfullscreen` attribute with this line :

```
parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute('allowFullScreen', 'true');
```

However, this does not work when displaying the published project from a local source (Cross-origin protection). It works fine when displayed from a webserver (even localhost).